# Gnome's ALT+F2 sometimes freezes while loading icon or completion

Tags: gnome

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> a lot in Gnome 2. But when I enter, say, `fir` it sometimes freezes for up to ten seconds in order to complete it to `firefox`. Sometimes, it completes, even got the icon loaded, but does not let me click on run. After a few seconds it just launches the program since I already clicked the button.

Is there any way to un-freeze this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the [Bug 133243](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133243) tracked at Gnome Bugzilla.

*Ross Girshick* made a theory trying to explain why this happens and proposed [some solutions that needs to be made at the code of the app](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133243#c3).

"The problem here, as noted, is that in order to fill g_complete every
file in the user's path is access'd and stat'd. This happens once
everytime the run dialog is created. On some systems this takes a long
time to complete (10-20 seconds on my old PIII 650 latop with gentoo).
However, once the kernel has cached the inodes it is much faster to
run in the future."